# make dictionary from list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of path like `['aaa/aaa.csv', 'aaa/bbb.csv', 'aaa/ccc.csv']`. 
How can it be converted to dictionary like `{'aaa':['aaa.csv', 'bbb.csv', 'ccc.csv']` and so on with first folder in path is equal to others?

I tried this code, but got confused what to do next.

```
list_split = [i.split('/') for i in list]

dic = {}
list_temp = []
for item in list_split:
    list_temp.append(item)
    if len(list_temp) < 2:
        pass
    else:
        for itemm in list_temp:
            pass
```

Comment: Just a word of warning: with the way you're currently using `split`, you may run into trouble if you encounter multiply nested directories, e.g. `/aaa/bbb/ccc.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dic = {}
lst = ['aaa/aaa.csv', 'aaa/bbb.csv', 'aaa/ccc.csv']
for item in lst:
    slash = item.find('/')
    key = item[:slash]
    val = item[slash+1:]
    if dic.has_key(key):
        dic[key].append(val)
    else:
        dic[key] = [val]

>>> dic
{'aaa': ['aaa.csv', 'bbb.csv', 'ccc.csv']}
```

Comment: Could clean up a bit with `for key,val in [x.split("/") for x in lst]:`

Answer (score 1):

```
original_list = ['aaa/aaa.csv', 'aaa/bbb.csv', 'aaa/ccc.csv', 'x/1.csv', 'y/2.csv']  # i added a couple more items to (hopefully) prove it works

dic = {}

for item in original_list:
    path = item.split('/')
    if path[0] not in dic:
        dic[path[0]] = []
    dic[path[0]].append('/'.join(path[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> L = ['aaa/aaa.csv', 'aaa/bbb.csv', 'aaa/ccc.csv']
>>> list_split = [tuple(i.split('/')) for i in L]
>>> newdict = {}
>>> for (key,item) in list_split:
    if key not in newdict:
        newdict[key]=[]
    newdict[key].append(item)
```

Output:

```
{'aaa': ['aaa.csv', 'bbb.csv', 'ccc.csv']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

paths = ['aaa/aaa.csv', 'aaa/bbb.csv', 'aaa/ccc.csv', 'bbb/ccc.csv', 'aaa/bbb/ccc.csv']
dict = defaultdict(list)
for *key, value in [x.split('/') for x in paths]:
    dict['/'.join(key)].append(value)

print(dict.items())
print(dict['aaa'])
```

This will also work for nested directories by putting the full path as the key.

Answer (score -1):

```
path_dict = {}

for path in path_list:
    if '/' in path:
        path_dict[path.split('/')[0]] = path.split('/')[1:]
```

Comment: What happens when you have 2 files with the same path?